# Ищу библиотеку, троичная логика

Tags: логика, php

Привет всем. Не попадалась ли кому случайно библиотечка/класс хотя бы с основными тернарными операциями? Могу реализовать сам, сперва хотелось убедиться, что это не есть велосипед. Не нагуглил (мог плохо гуглить).

Цель - просто интерес, практика, возможно какое-то использование в проектах, хотя пока трудновато представить. Что-то подсказывает, что можно отказаться от исключений.

Кто не в курсе - это логика не 1/0, а 1/0/-1. Пару лет назад такое писал, но проект отправился в рай для жестких дисков. Код получался примерно такой:

```
// true3=1="да", false3=-1="нет", null3=0="не знаю"
$systemStatus = and3($s1->getstatus(), $s2->getstatus(), $s3->getstatus());
if ($systemStatus === true3) {
  echo 'all systems: ready';
  } elseif ($systemStatus === false3) {
  echo 'all systems: idle';
  } else echo 'malfunction';
```

**PS: Ничего общего с тернарным оператором**.

Comment: @Sh4dow, имхо, быстрее самому написать. =)

Comment: @ling, та да, но литературы тоже немного по ней. Импликации всякие переосмысливать надо, а насколько я припоминаю, у нее еще свои уникальные операции были.

Comment: @Sh4dow, а вы уверены, что видели это дело под php?
И логика, скорее, троичная (трёхзначная), чем тернарная, имхо.

По теме:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ternary_logic

http://trinary.ru/trinary/

Comment: @Dex, в первых двух ссылках "ternary", хотя спорить не буду. Trinary.ru я луркал, но там какие-то мутные ребята: возникло ощущение, что основное их занятие - придумывание страшных слов) Система записи через "0, -, +" тоже мозг разнесла. Т.е. они сперва заняли плюс, потом начали придумывать символ сложения, потом додумались числа в кавычках писать (`x = "-0+" + "--" - "+-"`). В общем, их подход не понравился, мягко говоря. И да, я не видел этого дела нигде (только для C что-то было), потому и ищу)

Comment: Я другого не понимаю, какой смысл использования этого типа логики в обычном программировании не имея процессора, работающего с ней?

P.S. ternary - в переводе с англицкого троичный, но дело ваше

Comment: @Dex, тем не менее ternary operator - тернарный оператор :) Да, считайте личным заскоком, трехзначный - это "135" или "999", троичный - "0,1,2", а вот ["арность"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и там же "тернарный" как пример.

Смысл - ну, это все-таки естественная логика. Для php эти потери в скорости небольшие, а результат может быть интересный (просто чутье). И да-да-да, для меня первично знание, а потом уж польза от него. Мне это интересно) 

У меня ж тут каждый второй вопрос такой))

Comment: @Sh4dow, значит хватит печатать, начинайте реализовывать, вопросы задавайте тут, а то блин уже заразили...

p.s. вот, вы верную ссылку дали

> А́рность предиката, операции или функции в математике — количество их аргументов, или операндов
> В общем случае предикат с n аргументами называют n-арным.

отсюда и тернАРНЫЙ, принимающий три аргумента. А значит "арность" неприменима к логике. Кстати, тут же форум лингвистов (филологов) открылся, надо и там засветиться, пусть решают)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взялся сам :)

[Ссылка на тестер](http://tools.sh4dow.ru/l3/) (там же можно [скачать класс](http://tools.sh4dow.ru/download/?file=class.l3.php) и посмотреть таблицы истинности), листинг основных операторов для будущих поколений:

```
define('TRUE3',   1);
define('NULL3',   0);
define('FALSE3', -1);

function l3validate(&$arg) {
  if ($arg !== FALSE3 and $arg !== NULL3 and $arg !== TRUE3) {
    $arg = NULL3;
    return FALSE3;
    }
  return TRUE3;
}

function l3not($a) { // НЕ, инверсия
  l3validate($a);
  if ($a === TRUE3) return FALSE3;
  if ($a === FALSE3) return TRUE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3and($a, $b) { // И, конъюнкция
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === TRUE3 and $b === TRUE3) return TRUE3;
  if ($a === FALSE3 or $b === FALSE3) return FALSE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3andm() { // И, несколько аргументов
  $result = TRUE3;
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
    l3validate($arg);
    if ($arg === NULL3) $result = NULL3;
    if ($arg === FALSE3) return FALSE3;
  }
  return $result;
}
function l3or($a, $b) { // ИЛИ, дизъюнкция
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === $b and $a === FALSE3) return FALSE3;
  if ($a === TRUE3 or $b === TRUE3) return TRUE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3orm() { // ИЛИ, несколько аргументов
  $result = FALSE3;
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
    l3validate($arg);
    if ($arg === NULL3) $result = NULL3;
    if ($arg === TRUE3) return TRUE3;
  }
  return $result;
}
function l3xor($a, $b) { // ЛИБО ... ЛИБО ..., строгая дизъюнкция
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === $b and $a !== NULL3) return FALSE3;
  if (($a === TRUE3 and $b === FALSE3) or ($a === FALSE3 and $b === TRUE3)) return TRUE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3imp($a, $b) { // ->, импликация 
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === FALSE3 or $b === TRUE3) return TRUE3;
  if ($a === TRUE3 and $b === FALSE3) return FALSE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3bimp($a, $b) { // <-, обратная импликация
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === TRUE3 or $b === FALSE3) return TRUE3;
  if ($a === FALSE3 and $b === TRUE3) return FALSE3;
  return NULL3;
}
function l3eq($a, $b) { // =, эквивалентность
  l3validate($a);
  l3validate($b);
  if ($a === NULL3 or $b === NULL3) return NULL3;
  if ($a === $b) return TRUE3;
  return FALSE3;
}
```

**ЗЫ:** Специально для @Dex: [обсуждение терминов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F), таки ваша взяла) Но все же посмотрите обсуждение, оно оказалось сложным и чисто эстетическим. Даже вариант "трехвалентная" был бы верным лексически %)

**UPDATE:** Исправил "идейно", любое "неопознанное" превращается в NULL3. *Если хочется быть более толерантным, в классе есть метод `cast`, округляющий до ближайшего из логических.*

Comment: Not можно проще)

  l3not($a): return -$a;

Comment: Тут многие функции уже на идеологии троичной логики, но ее осознание только процессе, потому не все) 

    echo l3not(15); // 0
    echo l3not(-250); // 0
    echo l3not(array(1 => 5)); // 0

Вообще у меня стойкое ощущение, что это не "просто добавили символ и пересчитали", а намного глубже =/

Comment: Имею в виду, что будет относительно простое арифметическое выражение...

А вот `l3not(15);` - это уже другое) проще класс, и проверка в конструкторе)) а вместо методов экземпляров - статические...

Comment: чем хуже

    if (!in_array($arg, array(FALSE3, NULL3, TRUE3))) return NULL3;

?) *Это есть в мульти-функциях, таки надо бы везде добавить.*

То есть, что происходит: вы спрашиваете "завтра будет тепло?" и вам отвечают либо "да", либо "нет", либо "хз, погугли")). Если вам ответят на иврите (`15`) или китайском (`new stdClass`), это абсолютно равнозначно ответу "не знаю".

Comment: @Sh4dow, мерси, конечно. Но, если вы позволите, я продолжу. Почему вы выбрали именно такие названия функций (префикс `l3`)? Вместо того, чтобы следовать той же нотации, что и вначале, когда определили TRUE3, FALSE3, NULL3. Т.е. `not3`, `and3`...

Comment: А вы проверяли на данной логике основные тожества булевой алгебры? Я думаю, что немаловажно так же вывести/проверить их, например из простейшего:

    not(x ^ y) = not(x) v not(y)

Comment: @Dex, в основном файле есть класс `l3` и операторы выглядят типа `l3::Oimp`. Было много всяко-разных причин, из них мало объективных, прошу простить) Все делалось для удобного обращения с `l3e/l3t/l3ParseExpression`.

п.2: 

    foreach (array(FALSE3, NULL3, TRUE3) as $x) {
      echo "\n";
      foreach (array(FALSE3, NULL3, TRUE3) as $y)
        echo "| ".l3t('!', l3t($x, 'and', $y))." ".l3t('!', $x, 'or', '!', $y)." |"; // !(x and y) _ !x or !y 
    }
    // output:
    | T T || T T || T T |
    | T T || N N || N N |
    | T T || N N || F F |